Why does a module has to provide the imports for required static references?
I am migrating my Web project into java modules (JigSaw) with Java 17 and eclipse. One of my projects (ProjectA) defines Lombok as a required static resource ("requires static lombok;") in the module-info.java.
The other project (ProjectB) which is using project ProjectA is now throwing an error:
java.lang.module.FindException: Module lombok not found, required by ProjectA.
ProjectA is referenced in the module-info.java of ProjectB
"requires ProjectA;".
As I understood "required static" defines a compile-time dependency. Why should ProjectB now have to provide this library?
Regards

Is it throwing an exception during compile time? Have you ensured lombok is there on the module path?

The compilation of ProjectB is throwing the exception and ProjectB is not using lombok. Before Java9 this dependency was not needed for ProjectB.

Requires static is indeed for optional dependencies. Can you share a more detailed error message?
